# Missing gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer, video4linux

I've never used gstreamer before but I'm trying to use it and video4linuxloopback to turn my IPad into a jury-rigged webcam. I have an app that outputs the video from the camera to an IP on the local network but no matter what I did I kept getting an EOS from "pipeline0". When trying to run it with decodebin to see if it could auto-detect what it needed, it says that it needs a plugin for text/html but I can't seem to find it, assuming it exists. Here's the full log

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.1.6/ ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'souphttpsrc0': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
Missing element: text/html decoder
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
../gst-plugins-base/gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c(4678): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: text/html (text/html)

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: What protocol is being used for the communication? IT just looks like GStreamer does not understand how to decode the stream. Therefore it says a plugin is missing - it thinks there may be a plugin that understands what you are sending.. but should figure what you are dealing with in the first place.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I think it's just constantly refreshing PNG images but using pngdec just gives me an EOS from "pipeline0" so I tried letting it auto-pick in case I was wrong, the app description isn't really clear on how it displays it, here's the link to it if you see anything I don't https://apps.apple.com/us/app/instant-webcam/id683949930